# I want to vertically create columns with bootstrap grid and I don't know how to do it

Tags: bootstrap-4

[image] 
That's more or less the idea I have, I've been today coding and I didn't know how to do that. I more or less understand the grid system of rows and columns, what I don't know how to create a column vertically in the grid system. Sorry for the screen capture, but I'm late and I have to leave my house and I needed to ask this just now. 
Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make a row with two columns and add other rows in first column.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row" style="background-color: yellow">
        a
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="background-color: blue">
        a
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="background-color: brown">
        a
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="background-color: magenta">
        a
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color: red">
      <div class="row">
        b
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```